# moment.js - test if a date is today, yesterday, within a week or two weeks ago

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am trying with moment.js to know if a date is today, yesterday, 1 week ago, or older (2 weeks ago or more).

I already done that for the first two cases:

```
var today = moment().startOf('day');
var yesterday = moment().subtract(1, 'days').startOf('day');

if (moment(localTime).isSame(today, 'd')) // today
    // do something
if (moment(localTime).isSame(yesterday, 'd')) // yesterday
    // do something
```

Is that correct?

However, how could I check if a date is a week ago, or older (eg. two weeks ago)?

Comment: What is "1 week ago"? Before yesterday, but after last friday (because today is friday)?

Comment: Are you just looking for the `isBefore` and `isAfter` functions? Or something more?

Comment: @acdcjunior You got it, that's exaclty that. I should of say 7 days before.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Here's something that can be useful:

```
var REFERENCE = moment("2015-06-05"); // fixed just for testing, use moment();
var TODAY = REFERENCE.clone().startOf('day');
var YESTERDAY = REFERENCE.clone().subtract(1, 'days').startOf('day');
var A_WEEK_OLD = REFERENCE.clone().subtract(7, 'days').startOf('day');

function isToday(momentDate) {
    return momentDate.isSame(TODAY, 'd');
}
function isYesterday(momentDate) {
    return momentDate.isSame(YESTERDAY, 'd');
}
function isWithinAWeek(momentDate) {
    return momentDate.isAfter(A_WEEK_OLD);
}
function isTwoWeeksOrMore(momentDate) {
    return !isWithinAWeek(momentDate);
}

console.log("is it today? ..................Should be true: "+isToday(moment("2015-06-05")));
console.log("is it yesterday? ..............Should be true: "+isYesterday(moment("2015-06-04")));
console.log("is it within a week? ..........Should be true: "+isWithinAWeek(moment("2015-06-03")));
console.log("is it within a week? ..........Should be false: "+isWithinAWeek(moment("2015-05-29")));
console.log("is it two weeks older or more? Should be false: "+isTwoWeeksOrMore(moment("2015-05-30")));
console.log("is it two weeks older or more? Should be true: "+isTwoWeeksOrMore(moment("2015-05-29")));
```

[Check a **JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/cvm7yd80/) with more tests, so you can tweak for your exact case, if needed.

Comment: Very nice. I was trying to achieve it myself, and i wasn't so far from your solution, i just forgot the `clone()` and i got weird results because of that.

Comment: Yeah, that's because `moment()` objects are mutable. If you call `someDate.subtract()`, it actually changes `someDate`'s value. In many languages the date objects are immutable, thus moment.js's mutability can yield weird results indeed.

Comment: I don't think startOf() is necessary, except for A_WEEK_OLD

Comment: @Jonah notice that that `REFERENCE` is just fixed for testing, it could be anything in real life.

Comment: @acdcjunior I know, but isSame doesn't care if it's the start of the day that's it's comparing to

Comment: Remember to use `isSame(date, "day")` for dates that contains a time part.

Answer (score 30):

More precise answer as follows

```
var today = moment();
var yesterday = moment().subtract(1, 'day');

var engagementDate = (Date to be compare);

if(moment(engagementDate).isSame(today, 'day'))
  console.log('Today');
else if(moment(engagementDate).isSame(yesterday, 'day'))
  console.log('Yesterday');
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks @Gurpinder

Answer (score 7):

Simplest Solution for Today :

```
const result = moment(date).isSame(moment(), "day")
```

Simplest Solution for Yesterday :

```
const result = moment(date).isSame(moment().subtract(1, 'day'), "day")
```

Answer (score 4):

The [diff](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) function might be helpful for your case and, in general, to check the exact days since a date

```
var sampleDaysAgo = moment().subtract(28, 'days'); //28 just for test
var today = moment();

console.log(today.diff(sampleDaysAgo, 'days')); // 28
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uvdusjtr/)

Answer (score 0):

From version 2.14 onwards you can customize the `calendar()` function

```
moment().calendar(YOUR_DATE, {
  sameDay: function (now) {
    if (this.isBefore(now)) {
      return '[Will Happen Today]';
    } else {
      return '[Happened Today]';
    }
    /* ... */
  }
});
```

This is designed for 'calendar' type events.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/

Answer (score -1):

Moment already contains some logic of this nature

You may want to look at their source code for the `humanize` code 
https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/ed1fc742b179708d0a987a639979178616309f93/src/lib/duration/humanize.js

and the `fromNow` logic

https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/497f918515ae6ab900f008f19523b1e4ae5e2450/src/lib/moment/from.js

I found this useful to see how they did it.

The way you format the string will depend on your business, and to be honest the built in logic probably won't cut it most of the time. It seems to make sense for the date of a 'post' where 'a few days ago' is ok but I'm tracking packages in the mail and saying 'Your package shipped a few days ago' just isn't good enough.