# Javascript: Moment.js How to check if date is previous date

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I go through moment.js docs but not able to find if a date is previous date,

> ex 1

```
var date='2018/09/28';
//now I want to compare this with today's date
var today =  moment(new Date()).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
```

this should return true

ex 2

```
var date='2018/10/02';
//now I want to compare this with today's date
var today =  moment(new Date()).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
```

this should return false;

I acheived this with javascript,

> // I splitted days, months and year and compare with each other

but I want to know if there is something in moment to reduce my line of code?

Comment: a simple google should solve the problem right?

Comment: possible duplicate 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21284312/moment-js-check-if-a-date-is-today-or-in-the-future

Comment: I think your answer is already present [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668373/moment-js-test-if-a-date-is-today-yesterday-within-a-week-or-two-weeks-ago)

Comment: You have gone through momentjs docs but couldn't find it?? I suggest you check the docs once again plz.

Comment: @mckuok a simple google did not solved my problem thats why i asked it on stack

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`isBefore`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/) to compare two dates in moment.

```js
console.log(moment('2018/09/28', "YYYY/MM/DD").isBefore(moment()));
console.log(moment('2018/10/02', "YYYY/MM/DD").isBefore(moment()));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```