# Saving updates into localstorage and having a history of previous inputs

Tags: javascript, html, session, local-storage

I have the following code, and what I'm trying to do is save the chosen date and time with every button click to have a record of the previous inputs or sessions even after refreshing the page, additionally each session should be limited by 5 clicks tops.

```js
function store()  {
    
    var time = document.querySelector("option").innerText;
    var date = document.querySelector("input").value;

    localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(time), date);
    console.log(localStorage);

    //store in object
    const items = { ...localStorage};
    console.log(Object.entries(items))
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Performax Cinema</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="date" id="date" required/>
    
    <select id="time" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="0">10:00 AM - 12:00 PM</option>
        <option value="1">12:00 AM - 14:00 PM</option>
        <option value="2">14:00 AM - 16:00 PM</option>
        <option value="3">16:00 AM - 18:00 PM</option>
        <option value="4">18:00 AM - 20:00 PM</option>
        <option value="5">20:00 AM - 22:00 PM</option>
    </select>
    <button id="btn" onclick="store()">add</button>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store history in some key in local storage and access it with that key once refresh. Store click counts in local storage too and checks it every time before saving it. If the limit is reached, don't store it.

```js
  

    function store() {
  let clickCounter = localStorage.getItem("clickCount");
  if (!clickCounter) {
    localStorage.setItem("clickCount", 0);
    clickCounter = "0";
  }
  clickCounter = parseInt(clickCounter);
  if (clickCounter == 5) {
    console.log("Limit reached");
    return;
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("clickCount", clickCounter + 1);
  }
  console.log("Saving");
  var time = document.querySelector("option").innerText;
  var date = document.querySelector("input").value;

  localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(time), date);

  console.log(localStorage);
  if (!localStorage.getItem("history")) {
    localStorage.setItem("history", "[]");
  }
  //store in object
  const history = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("history"));
  history.push({ [JSON.stringify(time)]: date });
  localStorage.setItem("history", JSON.stringify(history));
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("history"));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Performax Cinema</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="date" id="date" required />

  <select id="time" class="form-control" required>
    <option value="0">10:00 AM - 12:00 PM</option>
    <option value="1">12:00 AM - 14:00 PM</option>
    <option value="2">14:00 AM - 16:00 PM</option>
    <option value="3">16:00 AM - 18:00 PM</option>
    <option value="4">18:00 AM - 20:00 PM</option>
    <option value="5">20:00 AM - 22:00 PM</option>
  </select>
  <button id="btn" onclick="store()">add</button>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer has definitely helped but if you take a look at the console.log it looks like this:                                                                          
{"clickCount":"17","\"10:00 AM - 12:00 PM\"":"","history":"{\"clickCount\":\"16\",\"\\\"10:00 AM - 12:00 PM\\\"\":\"\",\"history\":\"{\\\"clickCount\\\":\\\"15\\\",\\\"\\\\\\\"10:00 AM - 12:00 PM\\\\\\\"\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"history\\\":\\\"{\\\\\\\"clickCount\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"14\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"10:00 AM - 12:00 PM\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"history\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"

Comment: Additionally I wanted to ask how do I implement a statement to check if the input date a more than a week old and more than a week in the future and return an error message if it is? Thanks a lot again and I do appreciate the help

Comment: @Rafat updated the answer. Please check

Comment: to do a date comparison I guess you should use the moment js library. It is widely used for such scenarios.

Comment: here is one link which can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/30674186/4045916

Comment: My final question, when I try to select the time, it ends up always printing the first option regardless of what I choose, I'd go with time input however it doesn't have cross platform compatibility

Comment: you actually trying to access the element using a selector which will give the first one always, not the selected option. I changed it to get it by the selected value.

Comment: here is the codepen link too. https://codepen.io/technotech/pen/bGaxrzM

Comment: @TechoTech I just wanted to ask if there is a way to retrieve data from local storage? so that when choosing a date and time, I cannot choose it again? This is the last thing I seem to be stuck on